# How to get console.clear() to not give a message after clearing

Tags: javascript

When ever I use console.clear() it says in console, "Console was cleared.  Is there a way to clear the console without this outputting?[image: This is what apears]

Comment: not according to mdn...

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal but you could print a bunch of blank lines like so:

```
console.clear();
console.log(Array(100).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to clear the console messages, why not try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, it works well.

Comment: I have same question because the console is a part of my app. Console for customers to debug, not developer.

Comment: en, I think there must exist some way to clear message in the console, maybe it is invoking some api, but not by hitting the Ctrl + L, you need do some further search