# Clear browser console including 'Console was cleared' statement - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser-console

I would like the console to be completly cleared whenever I call the `console.clear()` function

However, is there any way to remove the 'Console was cleared' text once that function has been run? I don't mind it normally, but in this case it would be very helpful if there was a solution.

[image]

Comment: what is your usecase here? local development?

Comment: yes, local development.

Comment: this is a browser behaviour. you can go around it manually by reloading the page when you need to or with the ctrl + l shortcut

Comment: also you might want to play around with console groups. it will help namespace logs so its easier to find / inspect them

Comment: Related: [How to get console.clear() to not give a message after clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799053/how-to-get-console-clear-to-not-give-a-message-after-clearing)

Comment: Oops, didn't spot that one - the answer is almost identical!

Comment: Technically, it doesn't count as a duplicate because no answer was selected for the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always print loads of lines to hide any messages in the console that were there before hand.

```js
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

Or the short version which is

```js
console.log('\n'.repeat('25'));
```

It is not the best solution but it does work in your case if you don't want the message to say that the console has been cleared

Comment: If that's the only way around it, thanks. It works nicely with this technique and the text doesn't jump around as it did before.